# Debugging R scripts through Visual Studio

Tags: r, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, r.net

I have a vb.net program which processes some data and user input and then uses R.net to set this information into R objects and run R scripts on these objects.

My problem is that this is hard for me to debug, as the error messages that bubble back up through the Visual Studio debugger about the R scripts are often not helpful.

My latest solution to this is to add

```
engine.Evaluate("save.image('Scripts/debugging/image.RData')")
```

into my vb.net code just before the script that has an error. This allows me to load up the objects in my R IDE and check if everything is in the form I expect it to be.

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this? For instance I wonder is it possible to set up the R environment/engine to run a `save.image()` if an error is encountered automatically?

Comment: Depending on the data, put some `dput` to capture the input and then debug the R outside Visual Studio. EDIT - actually, what data are you sending to your script?

Comment: I'm converting vb lists and textboxes into R vectors mostly.

Comment: Try to show the R code and sample inputs (the `dput` should help).